# NX React Standalone App Linter Infinite Loop

Tags: reactjs, eslint, nrwl-nx

I've come across an interesting scenario where running `nx lint` triggers a (seemingly) infinite loop.

For context, I've migrated my CRA app into a standalone NX react app - using `npx cra-to-nx` script. The app is building and running without error. However, when testing the linter, it appears to get stuck in a loop. The odd part is that if I generate a new library and target the linter to run on the new library it works as expected.

Any clue as to what the issue might be here? I don't receive any errors in the console (see screenshot below) so I don't really know where to look. I've tried making changes to `eslintrc` but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Hoping someone has run across a similar behavior with NX.

[image: console output]

**(EDIT)** nx.json targetDefaults:

```
"targetDefaults": {
    ...
    "lint": {
      "inputs": [
        "default",
        "{workspaceRoot}/.eslintrc.json",
        "{workspaceRoot}/.eslintignore"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Comment: Can you include your "targetDefaults" from the root "nx.json" or equivalent. Your logs suggest the lint target depends on itself

Comment: @AndrewAllen added `targetDefaults` in description

Comment: What seemed to fix it was adding a `targets.lint` property in `project.json`. I haven't modified this file since running `cra-to-nx` script, possibly a bug in the migration script?

Comment: Not sure. If in doubt, create a dummy Nx react workspace via create-nx-workspace and examine the files